# Type Error on uploading image files through django admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, amazon-s3

I've created a personal website/blog with python django, and as an admin, I want to create instances of that blog based on the django model and display it to the html page accordingly. That model basically consists of a Title field, TextArea field, and Image field. My app is currently deployed on Heroku, and I'm serving images using AWS S3 Buckets. Locally, when I create a blog instance through the django admin it is successful, but when I log into the django admin onto the deployed app on Heroku, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError at /admin/projects/project/add/

expected string or bytes-like object
```

and this is what appears in the console

```
was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure endpoint 'http://dpaste.com/'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.
```

Upon further research, It seems like the Image field is not the type of text or bytes when I upload from as a djagno admin and s3 is throwing an error failed. This is just a hunch, but any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add SSL to this domain `http://dpaste.com/` it looks like does not implemented and change it to `https://dpaste.com/` the error is due to unencrypted traffic in your webform